# Exception thrown when trying to create localdb using code first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm trying to use a code first approach to create a brand new database in Entity Framework to test my WPF Prism application. A new database should be created whenever the application is launched, due to this being a new project that will be changing rapidly during development.

I've run into the following exception when trying to create the database:

> "Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Edvard\SharedResources.DataAccess.EFDbContext.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.\r\nCREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

This is what the datacontext constructor looks like:

```
public EFDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new CustomInitializer<EFDbContext>());
}
```

As you can see above, I'm calling a custom initializer so that I can seed the database with information:

```
public class CustomInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
    {
        context.Users.Add(new User
        {
            SaveableClaims = new List<SaveableClaim>
            {
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.Username, Value = "Mark" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.HashedPassword, Value = "MB5PYIsbI2YzCUe34Q5ZU2VferIoI4Ttd+ydolWV0OE=" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.FirstName, Value = "Mark" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.LastName, Value = "Johnson" },

                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.UIAccess, Value = UIAccessTypes.SearchMenuRead }
            }
        });

        context.Users.Add(new User
        {
            SaveableClaims = new List<SaveableClaim>
            {
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.Username, Value = "John" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.HashedPassword, Value = "hMaLizwzOQ5LeOnMuj+C6W75Zl5CXXYbwDSHWW9ZOXc=" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.FirstName, Value = "John" },
                new SaveableClaim { Type = CustomClaimTypes.LastName, Value = "Markson" }
            }
        });

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong the in the above code that might be causing this? To provide some additional detail, I'm using localdb. This is the App.config file:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

If there's more information I can provide please let me know. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you using a connection string in the app.config?

Comment: I'm not @dustmouse, just indicating the connection factory.

Comment: Does that file exist, and if so, if you blow it away, do you still get the error?

Comment: @dustmouse, you were spot on! Found the files and deleted both, which fixed the problem. Feel free to add an answer for me to mark as correct :)

Comment: Does it generate the same error on subsequent runs?

Comment: It does not, from there it's creating a new database without issue as expected.

Comment: Okay, cool.  I'll post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the file located at:

> 'C:\Users\Edvard\SharedResources.DataAccess.EFDbContext.mdf'

And delete it.